# how to access strings between two special characters which the order of them is important?

Tags: java, string

I have an string:

`“/ontology/concepts.owl#Altitude>, /ontology/Concepts.owl#Height>”`

I want to find `“Altitude” and “Height”` by looking through the string to find two special characters (‘#’ and ‘>’)

The order of characters is important, for example `“>, /ontology/Concepts.owl”` shouldn’t be the result of String.split(“#|>”) which returns the result which includes `““>, /ontology/Concepts.owl”.` How can i find the right place in the string when doing this ?

Thanks in advance,

Soodeh

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```
    String s = "/ontology/concepts.owl#Altitude>, /ontology/Concepts.owl#Height>";
    Matcher m = Pattern.compile("#(.+?)>").matcher(s);
    while(m.find()) {
        System.out.println(m.group(1));
    }
```

output

```
Altitude
Height
```

Answer (score 0):

Check [Java's regex](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/package-summary.html) package. It is quite simple. All you need to do is create regular expressions matching your requirement